# When a property value is changed in a class via @Published, some of the observedObjects wont get updated?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

These are all the codes.

the SurveyQuestion class

```
class SurveyQuestion: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String

    init() {
        print("Initialising now ...")
        self.text = "HELLO"
        changeText()
    }

    func changeText() {
        print("Changing Text Now from \(text).. ")

        if self.text == "HELLO"{
            self.text = "BYE"
        }
        else{
            self.text = "HELLO"
        }


        print("to \(self.text) \n")


    }
}
```

SubView.swift

```
struct SubView: View {

    @ObservedObject var someOtherClass = SurveyQuestion()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Text now is \(someOtherClass.text)")

    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var someClass = SurveyQuestion()



    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Button(action: {
                print("Changing Text Now !")
                self.someClass.changeText()
            }) {
                Text("Change Text ")
            }

            Text("Text now is \(someClass.text)")

            SubView()

        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click 'changeText' button, it changes the text in  Text("Text now is (someClass.text)") but not Subview(). They should all be updated with the same text change. 
Any idea what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you should use *same* instance of ObservableObject, like below

```
struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var someOtherClass: SurveyQuestion // to be injected

    var body: some View {
        Text("Text now is \(someOtherClass.text)")

    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var someClass = SurveyQuestion() // created

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Button(action: {
                print("Changing Text Now !")
                self.someClass.changeText()
            }) {
                Text("Change Text ")
            }

            Text("Text now is \(someClass.text)")

            SubView(someOtherClass: someClass) // << injected

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `someClass` and `someOtherClass` are two completely different objects. Changing one has no effect on the other. If this was supposed to be a singleton observable that could affect different views simultaneously, you wanted an *environment* object.

Comment: Or, as Asperi rightly says, pass the same object down the hierarchy.